# Loop and Functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I'm having troubles gathering information about clicked eventListeners.

I have this loop which builds an array:

```
myButtonList = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
myAnchorList = [];

for (i=0; i < myButtonList.length;i++) {
    if (myButtonList[i].getAttribute('class') == 'flagged') {
        myAnchorList.push(myButtonList[i]);
    }
}
```

For each `<a>` put into `myAnchorList` array, I also create another array storing other informations from the same tag (classe and other atrributes).

Here's where I'm struggling. I'm trying to set up an eventListener to send me back those information when those `<a>` are being clicked. But somehow, the fact that I create a function (for the eventListener) within a loop breaks everything.

```
for (i=0; i < myAnchorList.length; i++) {
    myAnchorList[i].addEventListener("click", function(i){
        console.log(alpha+' - '+beta[i]+" - "+charlie[i]);
    });
}
```

My values will either be `undefined` or some other values which will be the same for each buttons I clicked. `alpha` is working well as it doesn't depend on any iteration of the loop, but not the others.

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Try using `myButtonList[i].className` or `myButtonList[i].classList.contains("flagged")`

Comment: Another error you have here is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968147/passing-parameters-on-event-listeners-with-loops), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909652/adding-click-event-listeners-in-loop) and others

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I saw a few on the same topic but couldn't quite relate to my examples. Yours really helped, cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < myAnchorList.length; i++) {
    (function (i) { //Passes i to your function
        myAnchorList[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            console.log(alpha+' - '+beta[i]+" - "+charlie[i]);
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm, just like the examples other people gave me. You rock !

Answer (score 0):

The variable "i" in closure that you created in the loop will always retrieve the last value(myAnchorList.length - 1). You shouldn't create closure in a loop, and you can use a "factory" method to create closure instead.